# Javax.mail package didn't work in release mode apk

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I'm using javax.mail package for mail sending,
while application in debug mode it's work fine and send every mail to my account, but when i create release application mail stop sending form application.
code is as given below:

```
   Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", "abc@xyz.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    //Creating a new session

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        //Authenticating the password
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("abc@xyz.com", "password@123");
        }
    });
    try {
        //Creating MimeMessage object
        MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

        //Setting sender address
        mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@xyz.com"));
        //Adding receiver
        mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("abc@xyz.com"));
        //Adding subject
        mm.setSubject(subject);
        //Adding message
        mm.setText(message);

        //Sending email
        Transport.send(mm);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally this problem happen because of proguard, If you add proguard into your project it'll stop some of functionality like this.

I did it by adding package javax in proguard-rules.pro file.

> -keep class javax.** {*;}

this will add all javax methods's  permission in proguard.